# Mongo $and selector

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

How does mongo $and selector work? I have trouble getting correct results back.

Let's say I have a collection something like this:

```
{ "_id" : "F7mdaZC2eBQDXA5wx", "quantity" : 5 }
{ "_id" : "F7mdaZC2eBQDXA5wx", "quantity" : 9 }
{ "_id" : "F7mdaZC2eBQDXA5wx", "quantity" : 34 }
{ "_id" : "F7mdaZC2eBQDXA5wx", "quantity" : 66 }
```

and I run query:

```
var selectorMin = 9;
var selectorMax = 42;

ScrapReport.find({ $and: [ { quantity: { $gte: selectorMin }, quantity: { $lte: selectorMax } } ] })
```

I would expect mongo to return me only 9 and 34. But for some reason it also returns 5 and 66.

What's wrong with my query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is returning all the documents in that sample because it is first looking for documents whose `quantity >= 9` i.e. 9, 34 and 66 **AND** combines that query with documents whose `quantity <= 42` i.e 34, 9 and 5. It's not looking for documents within a particular range but your query explicitly looks for all documents that satisify two ranges i.e.

```
Documents which satisfy "quantity >= 9"
+
Documents which satisfy "quantity <= 42"
```

not

```
Documents which satisfy "9 <= quantity <= 42"
```

Just simplify your query to

```
ScrapReport.find({ "quantity": { "$gte": selectorMin, "$lte": selectorMax } })
```

That way, you specify a range for MongoDB to filter your documents with i.e.

```
9 <= quantity <= 42
```

Specifying a comma separated list of expressions implies an implicit AND operation and use an explicit AND with the **[`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)** operator when when the same field or operator has to be specified in multiple expressions.

Comment: I did try that but its still returning me the same results as $and
edit: Sorry I saw now the difference, correct answer.

Comment: This describes the problem as if `$or` was used instead of `$and`. See @umesh's answer for the OP's real problem.

Answer (score 3):

Using an implicit AND operation like the other answers suggested would work. But I would like to dig deeper into the specifics. **Why is your query not working as you expected it to work?**

**Why?** Why is this *seemingly* correct query of yours returning not so correct results? After all, whether you use implicit or explicit AND operation should be a matter of **your** choice and you should be able to achieve your goal irrespective of which form you use. **How to make your query work with an explicit AND operation?**

Let us look at the syntax of the AND operation.

```
{ $and: [ { <expression1> }, { <expression2> } , ... , { <expressionN> } ] }
```

The value of your AND operator should be an array containing expressions on which you would like to perform the AND operation.

After a first glance at your query, everything looks fine. But if you take a moment to look deeper, you would see that your query is not matching the AND syntax exactly. It is still syntactically correct. No doubt about that. But it is logically incorrect. I will explain how.

This is your `$and` operator value

```
{ $and: [ { quantity: { $gte: selectorMin }, quantity: { $lte: selectorMax } } ] }
```

You think you have an expression1 `quantity: { $gte: selectorMin }` and an expression2 `quantity: { $lte: selectorMax }`. An AND operation with these expressions should return the documents with quantity 9 and 34. But actually, all you have is **one expression**. Pay close attention to the braces. You have added both these expressions in a single `{}` block. Do you see it? So effectively, there is no 2nd expression for the AND operator to work with. But AND operator requires *two or more expressions* to function properly.

So your query is of the form

```
{ $and: [ { <expression1> } ] }
```

With an incorrect form, the results will also be incorrect. The correct query using an **explicit AND operation** would be

```
ScrapReport.find({ $and: [ { quantity: { $gte: selectorMin } }, { quantity: { $lte: selectorMax } } ] })
```

Do you see the difference? Try this query and you will get the results that you expected in the first place.

If you are not satisfied by just having the answer and are curious to know how Mongo interpreted your first query, read further.

Consider this query

```
ScrapReport.find({ quantity: 9 })
```

What would you expect the result to be? If you expected Mongo to return a single document whose value in the quantity field is 9, you are right. That is exactly what the result is. Now consider the same query with a small twist.

```
ScrapReport.find({ quantity: 9, quantity: 5 })
```

What would the result be now? Things are getting interesting now, huh? If you execute this query and have a look at the result, you will still see only a single document. But the value in the quantity field is 5. Now that is interesting!

```
ScrapReport.find({ quantity: 9, quantity: 5, quantity: 34 })
```

What about this? The result is still a single document with value in the quantity field being 34. You can try other combinations. What you will find out is this -

> Within an expression, if you are referencing a field multiple times, the result will be determined by the last reference to that field in that expression.

Now apply this concept to your original query. It has already been pointed out that you have a *single* expression with two parts `quantity: { $gte: selectorMin }` and `quantity: { $lte: selectorMax }`. Since within an expression, you are referring to the same field twice, only the last one will be relevant. The selection criteria will be `quantity: { $lte: selectorMax }`. The result will be 3 documents with quantity values 5, 9 and 34.

If you swap the order i.e. write `quantity: { $lte: selectorMax }` first and then `quantity: { $gte: selectorMin }`, the selection criteria will now be determined by `quantity: { $gte: selectorMin }`. The result will be 3 documents with quantity values 9, 34 and 66.

Although it wasn't your intention, your original query is effectively

```
ScrapReport.find({ quantity: { $gte: selectorMin }, quantity: { $lte: selectorMax } })
```

When you miss braces or add them at the wrong position, it can completely change the meaning of your query.

> **Moral** - Pay close attention to where you place your braces in complex queries.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have two problems in there:

Your query is equivalent to the following:

```
ScrapReport.find( { "$and": [{ "quantity": { "$lte": selectorMax } } ] } )
```

or even better:

```
ScrapReport.find( { "quantity": { "$lte": selectorMax } } )
```

The reason is because duplicate key are allowed in JSON document but the last value for a given key is maintained.

So this will only return all those documents where "quantity" is less than or equal `selectorMax`.

The second problem is already mentioned in @chridam's answer so the right query is:

```
ScrapReport.find({ "quantity": { "$gte": selectorMin, "$lte": selectorMax } })
```